# Object [id=null] was not of the specified subclass [com.pfe.dashboard.model.Test] : class of the given object did not match class of persistent copy

Tags: java, oop, thymeleaf

I'm encountering an error in my code when calling the **`initialize()`** method to save a project. The code snippet where the error occurs is as follows:

Code :

```
@GetMapping("/analytics")
public String analyticsPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
    try {
        UserEntryDto user  = cookieUtils.getCookieValue(request);
        String userAvatar = gitlabClient.getUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        List<ProjectDto> projects = projectService.loadUserProjects( user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),user.getCName());

        List<ProjectDto> projectList = projects.stream()
                .map(projectDto -> {
                    Project project  = modelMapper.map(projectDto, Project.class);
                    Project project1 = testService.initialize(project);
                    ProjectDto projectDto1 = modelMapper.map(project1, ProjectDto.class);
                    return projectDto1;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("projects", projectList);
        model.addAttribute("userAvatar", userAvatar);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return "error-500";
    }

    return "analytics";
}
```

```
public Project initialize(Project project){

    PerformanceTest performanceTest = testRepository.getLatestPerformanceTest(project.getId(), PERFORMANCE_TEST);
    FunctionalTest functionalTest = testRepository.getLatestFunctionalTest(project.getId(), FUNCTIONAL_TEST);
    UnitTest unitTest = testRepository.getLatestTest(project.getId(), UNIT_TEST);

    int unitTestPassed = 0;
    int unitTestFailed = 0;
    int skipped = 0;
    int performanceTestPassed = 0;
    int performanceTestFailed = 0;
    int functionalTestPassed = 0;
    int functionalTestFailed = 0;

    if(unitTest != null) {
        unitTestPassed =  unitTest.getPassed();
        unitTestFailed = unitTest.getFailures();
        skipped = unitTest.getSkipped();
    }
   if (performanceTest != null ) {
        performanceTestFailed = performanceTest.getTotalFailed();
        performanceTestPassed = performanceTest.getTotalPassed();
    }
    if(functionalTest != null ) {
        functionalTestPassed = functionalTest.getNbPassed();
        functionalTestFailed = functionalTest.getNbFailed();
    }
    project.setTotalPassed(unitTestPassed + performanceTestPassed + functionalTestPassed );
    project.setTotalFailed(unitTestFailed + performanceTestFailed + functionalTestFailed);
    project.setTotalSkipped(skipped);
    return projectRepository.save(project);
}
```

The **`initialize()`** method is responsible for saving the project, but it's throwing an exception. I have already ensured that the values passed to the method are correct. However, I'm not sure why this error is happening or how to fix it.

The error message I'm getting when the exception is thrown is:

"org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException:Object [id=null] was not of the specified subclass [com.pfe.dashboard.model.Test] : class of the given object did not match class of persistent copy"

I have already checked the relevant parts of the code, and all variables in initialize() method are pussed as it should be.

Classes :

Test

```
package com.pfe.dashboard.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Test {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column()
    private String type;
    @Column()
    private String testedAt;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;
}
```

PerformanceTest :

```
package com.pfe.dashboard.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class PerformanceTest extends Test{

    @Column()
    private int totalPassed;
    @Column()
    private int totalFailed;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "performanceTest", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<HttpSample> result;

    public void initialize(){
        this.totalFailed=0;
        this.totalPassed=0;
        this.getResult().forEach(result ->{
            if(result.getStatus().equals("true")){this.totalPassed++;}
            if(result.getStatus().equals("false")){this.totalFailed++;}
        });
    }
}
```

FunctionalTest :

```
package com.pfe.dashboard.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class FunctionalTest extends Test{

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    Long duration;
    @Column()
    private int nbPassed;
    @Column()
    private int nbFailed;
    @Column()
    private Long AvgDuration;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "functionalTest", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Feature> featureList;

    //method to set the nbPassed, nbFailed, AvgDuration and to set the Ids
    public void initialize(){
        this.nbFailed = 0;
        this.nbPassed = 0;
        duration= 0L;
        this.getFeatureList().forEach(feature -> {
            feature.getScenarioList().forEach(scenario -> {
                //assign feature to scenario
                scenario.setFeature(feature);
                scenario.getStepList().forEach(step -> {
                    //assign scenario to step
                    step.setScenario(scenario);
                    //assign result to step
                    step.getResult().setStep(step);
                    //set the nbFailed, nbPassed
                    if(step.getResult().getDuration() != null) { duration+=step.getResult().getDuration();}
                    if(step.getResult().getStatus().equals("passed")){this.nbPassed++;}
                    else if (step.getResult().getStatus().equals("failed")) {this.nbFailed++;}
                });
            });
        });
        //set the AvgDuration
        this.AvgDuration = duration/(this.nbFailed + this.nbPassed);
    }
}
```

UnitTest :

```
package com.pfe.dashboard.model;


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import java.util.List;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "UnitTest")
@Getter
@Setter
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class UnitTest extends Test{

    @Column()
    private String name;
    @Column()
    private Double time;
    @Column()
    private int tests;
    @Column()
    private int skipped;
    @Column()
    private int failures;
    @Column()
    private int passed;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unitTest", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TestCase> testcases;

}
```

Project :

```
package com.pfe.dashboard.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table
public class Project {

    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column()
    private String name;
    @Column()
    private String createdAt;
    @Column()
    private String description;
    @Column()
    private int totalPassed;
    @Column()
    private  int totalFailed;
    @Column()
    private int totalSkipped;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Test> testList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserProject> userProjects;

}
```

I expect to get a list of projects, every project has the totalPassed ..etc